# Excel imported data #value error

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, import

I am trying to manipulate data imported to Excel by websites.

I imported data from:
https://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?a=&b=&c=&d=8&e=5&f=2015&g=d&s=msft&ql=1
to Excel, using the "Get data from Web" function.

However, I get an "#VALUE" error everytime I calcule using the imported cells.

In the table, all the data is imported from the Yahoo Finance website:
[image: In this example, I tried to calcule "=G7*E7"]

Why do I always get an error message, while trying to use these numbers? I even tried to use =VALUE, but I get 0 as the answer, always.

Comment: What cells in row 7 are you trying to calculate, and what function are you using?

Comment: @BillOer In the picture, G7*E7. 
But any operation with any of the cells returns me an error message :(

Comment: Okay, my bad! But what good is (essentially) squaring the Close? What am I missing? And I do not get the #VALUE error doing the same thing.

Comment: It sounds like the numbers imported as text for some reason.  Right click and see if you can change the format to a number format.

Comment: @Tyson Yes, I thought the same!
I changed several times in "Format cells" and it didn't work. Same error.

Comment: According to Excel's help, you can get this error if you import external data and the external source is unavailable.

Comment: @BillOer I tried to refresh the table. I also tried to create a new spreadsheet with the same website, and had no problem creating both. Still #value error in both.

Also tried to import this table to another pc with other Excel version. Same results. Still no idea what is causing this weird problem.

Comment: @weber, I cannot re-create it myself. Can you post it to dropbox or something?

Comment: @BillOer Course! https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgrx4n40imep3of/example_internet_data.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: @weber, when I download your spreadsheet and edit in my machine, I cannot duplicate your error. I get the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is Excel is importing the data as Text.
You will have to do the following things:

- Format the cells to numbers
- If necessary change `.` to `,` depending on your location/settings
- All data has to be either manually re-enter (Step into the Cell and press Enter)

Or you will have to change the following settings in Excel:

In `Options -> Advanced -> Data delimiter`:
Change the Decimal from `,` to `.`

Comment: Thank you!
The problem was wrong decimal separator. 
After changed, the errors disappeared.

Comment: That explains why I couldn't duplicate @weber's error.

Answer (score 1):

Additional info; **converting TEXT values to NUMERIC**:

1. Type a single 1 *(the digit, one)* into a free cell.
2. Select that cell, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and hit <kbd>c</kbd> *(i.e. copy the content)*
3. Select the cells you wish to convert
4. Choose "Paste Special" (where it is depends on Excel version)
5. Make sure to select "Multiply" from the options in the dialog that
   opened.
6. Click OK or press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

*You may also " Add '0' " to achieve the same effect*